# Boot Windows 8 from HDD connected via USB port: OS not found error

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, boot, usb, ubuntu-14.04

I have internal SSD in my PC(I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on SSD). So I disassembled its HDD which has pre-installed Windows 8. So I want to boot my licensed and pre-installed Windows via USB. I connect it with converter cable(SATA to USB).

But the problem is when I try to boot USB connected HDD , It gives me error `Operation System Not Found..` in black screen only one line.

How can I solve this problem , and what is wrong in this situation?

Comment: Is there any other HDD/SSD in that notebook when you try to boot Ubuntu from SATA-USB connector? Is your disk available for boot priority in BIOS?

Comment: I have internal SSD only. I tried to boot my HDD connect via usb. I tried to boot legacy mode so I can choode usb port , But it says Operating System Not found.

Comment: Your Windows 8 system was probably installed in UEFI mode so it'll not boot in Legacy mode. You can try searching in your UEFI Setup settings if you can enable USB support in UEFI, although you've very low chances of being able to boot Windows 8 on USB. Default installation cannot do this, that's why Microsoft provides OnTheGo which enables installing Windows on a USB drive.

Comment: I will check again boot UEFI usb which is i didn't find yet. By the way does it matter secure boot on/off?

Comment: @piernov I added usb boot option but no way to boot win8, If I install like a usb stick on this HDD, can it work?

Comment: Are you able to browse the HDD by connecting it to any other laptop or Desktop?

Comment: @ali786 Yes I'm able to browse , on ubuntu system i see it has 4 partition(I dont't know which partition is what, I can look again). I think there is no connection issue. this is default Dell inspiron win8 pre-installed distro, is all problem is this?